# Я хотел сделать функцию автоматизированного создания случайных строк, из символов, добавленных в список, что не так?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
import random
from random import randint
from random import choice
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init 


print(Fore.GREEN)
print("Broot Force By GFX")
print("FirePhoenix corporation ©")
print(Fore.WHITE) 
length = randint(1,20)
symbols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
password = str()
for i in range(length):
   password+=random.choice(str(symbols))
print(password)
```

Broot Force By GFX
FirePhoenix corporation ©

'' x,',,n ,',''''''

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
from random import randint
from random import choice
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init 


print(Fore.GREEN)
print("Broot Force By GFX")
print("FirePhoenix corporation ©")
print(Fore.WHITE) 
length = randint(1,20)
symbols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
password = str()
for i in range(length):
   password+=str(random.choice(symbols)) # вот в этой строке была ошибка
print(password)
```

Суть ошибки заключалась в том, что вы не приводили к строковому виду случайную букву из списка, а случайно выбирали символ из строкового представления списка (это разные вещи). Нужно сначала выбрать элемент, а уже потом привести его к строке

Результат работы программы:

```
[32m
Broot Force By GFX
FirePhoenix corporation ©
[37m
6pqkkuyjdug96
```